# How can one read a list of text from divs in the most reliable way, using sibling relations in Selenium with Python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to locate and then read the list of text 1-5. All divs with **class="col-md-6"** have the same structure, so I'm trying to use the text from:

```
<h5>Header Unique Text</h5>
```

as it is the only unique element and then proceed to extract the texts but without using /div[x]/div[y] type xpath, as it won't be reliable in my case. I'm searching for a css selector(or even xpath) which uses sibling relations, maybe nth-child, related to the header tag or its parent div. However, I'm not sure you are even able to move backward in the DOM with css selectors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="row  dashboard-admin-widgets">
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5>Header Unique Text</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <div>Text 1</div>
                <div>Text 2</div>
                <div>Text 3</div>
                <div>Text 4</div>
                <div>Text 5</div>
     </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the last child as shown you can use a last-child selector

```
.col-md-6:last-child .ibox-content div
```

You could also use nth-of-type

```
.col-md-6:nth-of-type(n) .ibox-content div
```

Or even last-of-type

```
.col-md-6:last-of-type .ibox-content div
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to get the ancestor of `<h5>Header Unique text</h5>` like this:

```
//h5[normalize-space(.)='Header Unique Text']/ancestor::div[@class='ibox float-e-margins']/div[@class='ibox-content']/div
```

Let me break it down for you so you can adjust the xpath to your needs.

First, we look for `<h5>Header Unique text</h5>` and then we get its ancestor which is `div[@class='ibox float-e-margins']`. You can use any attribute, tag, just like you would write your xpath.

Now we are looking for elements in context of `div[@class='ibox float-e-margins']`. Then, use we look for all `div` elements with the text you desired.

Also, instead of using `/ancestor::div`, you can get first parent and look for it's sibling like this:

```
//h5[contains(text(), 'Header Unique Text')]/parent::div[@class='ibox-title']/following-sibling::div[@class='ibox-content']/div
```

Comment: you can use `ancestor` and access rather using `parent/parent`. Here is the update xpath for your reference. `//h5[normalize-space(.)='Header Unique Text']/ancestor::div[@class='ibox float-e-margins']/div[@class='ibox-content']/div`